# Dynamic proxy for concrete classes

Tags: java, reflection, dynamic-proxy

I want to define a method interceptor in a Java program in other words I want to have a behaviour which is executed at each method call.
This application isn't executed in an application server and therefore I can't use the EJB around invoke interceptors.
I have found a nice [Proxy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) API in the standard Java libraries but its limited because it needs an interface in the proxy creation:

```
 Foo f = (Foo) Proxy.newProxyInstance(Foo.class.getClassLoader(),
                                      new Class[] { Foo.class },
                                      handler);
```

Is there a similar API which doesn't force Foo.class to be declared as an interface?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use [CGLIB](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) ? See [this article](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2005/11/01/implement-proxy-based-aop.html) for more information.

> What if you want to proxy legacy classes that do not have interfaces?
>   You can use CGLIB. CGLIB is a powerful, high-performance code
>   generation library. Under the cover, it uses ASM, a small but fast
>   bytecode manipulation framework, to transform existing byte code to
>   generate new classes. CGLIB is faster than the JDK dynamic proxy
>   approach. Essentially, it dynamically generates a subclass to override
>   the non-final methods of the proxied class and wires up hooks that
>   call back to the user-defined interceptors.

Comment: I am new to CGLIB. My understanding is it generates class binary in memory, but the existing class loader just loads class from file system, so how it uses its own classloader?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no such API for classes. Many frameworks are using bytecode generation libraries like CGLIB to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of the mocking classes. The simplest approach may be to sub-class, your class. Or you could use AOP to inject the logging code you want.

Answer (score 0):

sun.misc.ProxyGenerator can be used to generate proxy classes and doesn't check that their "interfaces" are all interfaces. Its generateClassFile method gives you the bytecode as a byte array, which you can save to link into future builds or alter with third-party tools.

Note that if any of the "interfaces" has a final method, you'll get an error when you try to load the class.

Comment: `sun.misc.ProxyGenerator` is not available in newer java versions