# Use InvocationHandler and Proxy without using interface

Tags: java, reflection, dynamic, proxy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamic proxy for concrete classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878521/dynamic-proxy-for-concrete-classes)

Once I create a InvocationHandler implementation, I can use it with Proxy.newProxyInstance function to get a object behaving differently. In this case, I have to create a interface and its implementation class to use the Proxy.newProxyInstance function:

```
MyInterface objDest = Proxy.newProxyInstance(MyInterfaceImpl.class.getClassLoader(),   
        MyInterfaceImpl.class.getInterfaces(),   
        new MyInvocationHandler(new MyInterfaceImpl()));
```

Is it possible to do the same task directly using a simple class without interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [CGLIB](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) to create a dynamic proxy on a concrete class.