# Adding new method to a class through reflection

Tags: java, reflection

Is it possible to add a method to a class through reflection in java??

```
public class BaseDomain {

    public BaseDomain(){
        Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for(int i=0; i<fields.length; i++){
            String field = fields[i].toString();

            String setterMethod = "public void set" + field.toLowerCase();

            //Now I want to add this method to this class.

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680674/can-a-java-class-add-a-method-to-itself-at-runtime

Comment: What is the *actual problem* that you're trying to solve. There is probably an easier way to implement it.

Comment: This is what I want.....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482686/adding-getters-setters-to-one-base-class

Comment: @Tapas That doesn't add a new method. It just allows you to set a field through reflection.

Comment: @TapasJena - you want to automatically generate getters and setters? Your IDE does that, with far less effort than it will take you to implement an external solution.

Comment: Not exactly....I am searching for a solution like http://projectlombok.org . The problem with this library is It is forcing developer to install a plugin on IDE(Eclipse, Netbeans etc) which I cann't afford as I want this feature in a webframework.

Answer (score 13):

No, not through reflection.

Reflection asks about classes and their members, you can change fields but you cannot create new ones. You cannot add new methods.

You can use a a [bytecode manipulation library](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) to add methods to classes; but why would you want to?

You can't call the methods anyway except via reflection as they would obviously not exist at compile time.

Maybe take a look at [project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) - this is a annotation preprocessor that can add methods to classes at compile time. It will add getters and setters automagically as long as your classes are correctly annotated.

Comment: To add to Boris' answer, remember that you are using a statically typed language.  If you want something more dynamic then look into ruby or python

Comment: @Boris.....Pls check my previous post.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482686/adding-getters-setters-to-one-base-class

Comment: @TapasJena that question was about compile time generics this question is about runtime reflection - they aren't really related.

Comment: I want a compile time solution so that developers can use it as normally with full IDE support....Any idea?? BTW...that post was mine.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't add methods through reflection. In this case, I'll use a scripting language like [Beanshell 2](https://code.google.com/p/beanshell2/). Here's a DynamicObject class

```
public class DynamicObject
{

    bsh.Interpreter interpreter = null;

    public DynamicObject()
    {
        interpreter = new bsh.Interpreter();
    }

    public void addToSource(String... method)
    {
        try
        {
            String main = "";
            for (int i=0; i<lines.length; i++){
                main += lines[i] + "\n";
            }
            interpreter.eval(main);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Object invoke(String methodname, Object... args)
    {
        try
        {
            return interpreter.getNameSpace().invokeMethod(methodname, args, bsh);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Object invoke(String methodname)
    {
        return invoke(methodname, (Object[])null);
    }

}
```

Now an example dynamic object will look like

```
DynamicObject testObj = new DynamicObject();

testObj.addToSource(

    "public int add ( int a, int b )",
    "{",
        "return a+b;",
    "}"

);

int added = testObj.invoke( "add", 5, 4 );   // is 9
```